# microsoft-translator-api- Error retrieving translation: status code 400 in Java

Tags: java

I am working on my licence thesis and I have encountered a problem today while trying to run my program. I use microsoft-translator-api to translate some words from Romanian to English, and until now I've had no problem with the translation, everything worked fine, but starting two days ago I have noticed that I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : Server  returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13
at com.memetix.mst.MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.retrieveString(MicrosoftTranslatorAPI.java:202)
at com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:61)
at com.utcn.translator.Translator.translate(Translator.java:16)
at com.utcn.sentenceXmlParser.main.main(main.java:19)
```

My Translator class looks like this:

package com.utcn.translator;

```
import com.memetix.mst.detect.Detect;
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public abstract class Translator {

    public static String translate(String line) {
    Translate.setClientId(/*my client id*/);
    Translate.setClientSecret(/*my client secret*/);
    String translatedText = null;
        try {
            translatedText = Translate.execute(line, Language.ROMANIAN,
                    Language.ENGLISH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return translatedText;
}
}
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?

Best regards,
Roxana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

First of all I was making to much calls to the microsoft api. After I reduced that I could clearly see the problem. I was getting another exception becouse of a " that was in my text. It seems that microsoft translator api can't process that and it returns a ClassCastException!

Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is with your credentials. (`ClientId` and `ClientSecret`).
You can try setting credentials like below (Taken from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft-translator-java-api/VgnSgBUkN6c)).

```
Translate.setClientId("client id you type in the web site");
Translate.setClientSecret("secret  you type in the web site  in Base 64 format");
```

Comment: Hy, thank you for the answer, but the credentials are fine, my client secret is already in Base 64 format. I get some of the words translated and after a few translations i get that exception.

Comment: As microsof-ttranslaor-api is just an oAuth wrapper and makes http requests, you can [set a proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) and use an intercepting proxy tool (Like [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)) to investigate the actual request made to the server (By intercepting responses or setting a breakpoint on that part of the translator api you can also see the exact response)